# Python Dictionary into a CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm collecting tweets from Twitter's API. My code is returning a string which I have transformed into a dictionary. I am looking to create a CSV where I store this data by creating columns. I have attached an image of my CSV currently looks like.

current CSV image:

[image: current CSV image] .

What suggestions do you suggest for creating something like the following;

desired outcome:

[image: desired outcome]

```
    with open('dict.csv', 'w') as csv_file:  
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        for key, value in y.items():
           writer.writerow([key, value])
    #with open('my_file.csv', 'w') as f:
    #    [f.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(key, value)) for key, value in y.items()]
```

Full code:

```
import requests
import os
import json
import pandas as pd
import csv
import sys
import time

bearer_token = "insert here"

search_url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/all"

query_params = {'query': '(Johnson&Johnson) -is:retweet -is:verified -baby -lotion -shampoo','tweet.fields': 'text', 'tweet.fields':'created_at', 'start_time':'2021-01-20T00:00:01.000Z', 'end_time':'2021-02-17T23:30:00.000Z'}
#query_params={'query':'(vaccine OR vaccinated) -is:retweet -is:verified -RT -baby -lotion -shampoo&start_time=2021-01-20T00:00:01.000Z&end_time=2021-02-20T23:30:00.000Z&max_results=10&tweet.fields=author_id,conversation_id,created_at,geo,id,lang,source,text&expansions=author_id&place.fields=full_name&user.fields=created_at,description,entities,id,location,name,url,username'}

def create_headers(bearer_token):
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(bearer_token)}
    return headers

def connect_to_endpoint(url, headers, params):
    response = requests.request("GET", search_url, headers=headers, params=params)
    print('first:', response.status_code)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(response.status_code, response.text)
    return response.json()

def main():
    headers = create_headers(bearer_token)
    json_response = connect_to_endpoint(search_url, headers, query_params)
    x = json.dumps(json_response,sort_keys=True)
    y = json.loads(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Don't attach images of text. Attach the text. Screenshots are completely useless to anyone who wants to work with your sample data.

Comment: have you tried ```df = pd.DataFrame(y["data"]) ; df.to_csv("result.csv")```?

Comment: Apart from that, there are hundreds (if not thousands) of answers that revolve around how to turn dicts into CSV in Python. Your question is not specific to Twitter, in fact it has nothing to do with Twitter at all. You simply have a list of dicts you got from *somewhere* and want to turn that into CSV. Look around for existing answers for this topic and try a couple of them. When you have a specific question with an attempt of yours, you're welcome to ask it.

Answer (score 1):

Try Using DictWriter,

```
import csv
with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
    writer.writeheader()
    for data in dict_data:
        writer.writerow(data)
```

For more info refer below link,

[How to save a Python Dictionary to a CSV File?](https://geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-save-a-python-dictionary-to-a-csv-file/)